# Excel for how to find maximum

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a question on how to find the maximum total freight weight for the truck numbers and colors specified below using excel spreadsheet?

FYI just by looking at the numbers and color of the trucks, it is easy to identify that the green trucks have more freight weight of 300+300= 600Kg. This number is more than the sum of the freight weight compared to the other colored trucks. I have a large excel data with similar concept and would like to find an easier way of finding the maximum total weight of a specific color truck.

Please help

```
Truck Number    Truck Color    Freight Weight (Kg)
1                 Yellow       100
2                 Yellow       300
3                 Blue         200
4                 Orange       100
5                 Red          400
6                 Red          100
7                 White        150
8                 Green        300
9                 Green        300
10                Brown        100
```

Comment: You can use a Pivot Table.  Exactly how you want the results laid out is not clear, but explore the Pivot Table options until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PivotTable to summarize data

A PivotTable that summarizes the sum of freight weight by truck color allows you to find the maximum weight for a large set of data.

Using the example provided, build a pivot table with Truck Color in rows, and summary values as Sum of Freight Weight.

[image: build pivot table]

Modify the table by adding the formula `=MAX(B4:B10)` in cell `B11`. Add conditional formatting to the table to highlight the row or rows where column `B` matches the maximum value in `$B$11`.

[image: pivot table]

Expand the idea by adding Truck Number in columns of the pivot table. Enter the formula `=MAX(L5:L11)` in cell `L12`, and again add conditional formatting to highlight the row or rows where column `L` matches the maximum value in `$L$12`.

[image: pivot table with columns]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply filter for color and then use MAX function

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: The question asks "how", and this is more of a suggestion of a direction to investigate.  Can you expand your answer to illustrate the solution?

Comment: In the category name in this case truck color you select filter, then you get a button to show drop down menu in the cell. In the menu you select those colors you want to keep. After filter is applied you enter one cell with =MAX list of functions will popup and you select MAX then you select all wanted cells and it will show you highest value. If you want I can post some screenshots.

Comment: @Dušan, adding the description in your comment and some screenshots to your answer would be great (turn it into a real answer).  As a newcomer, you may not have enough rep to post pictures, but I'll be happy to help with that.  Just post links to any images at a sharing site, like imgur.com.  "Address" a comment to me with @, like I did here, and I'll get an alert.